# Install web sharing on OS X server without disk?

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx-server

On a new mac Mini which came with 10.6, I deselected the Web Sharing and a few other options on the initial setup, so now in System Preferences-->Sharing I have no option for Web Sharing, File Sharing, etc.

Now I want those items. I've since upgraded from 10.6 to 10.6.6 through the update manager, so now when I use my 10.6 to install over the network to the Mini, it says it can't proceed because a newer version of OS X is installed. How do I get the Web Sharing feature installed / enabled now? Do I need a 10.6.6 CD? I really don't have time to get a CD I just want the quickest path to getting this normal OS X feature installed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that if you're talking about Mac OS X Server, you don't control file sharing or web sharing through the standard "System Preferences" application, but either through "Server Preferences" (for simpler setups), or "Server Admin" (for more advanced configurations).

Comment: Oh so it's just me making assumptions and just not finding the documentation. The question itself is a little invalid then... I think I'll keep it open just for other people who might have a similar confusion. Thanks!